# Do we need to enlist dependencies in JSON file

Tags: composer-php

in **JSON** configuration file for installing a package. I saw many people enlisted dependencies in '**require**' section. And I read somewhere on the internet that said: "we don't need to specify dependencies for dependencies because those nested dependencies will all be taken care of by **Composer**". If that why we need to specify dependencies for the initial package (the first package we declare in **JSON** file). **Composer** also takes care of its dependencies, isn't it? :D.

Can some body point me out what's wrong with my thinking here?

Many thanks!

**Edit:** 
Sorry if I'm asking this simple question. However, AFAK, Composer docs doesn't cover this one. I don't know why those guys down voted my question without any comments or explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your thinking probably isn't wrong, but without an example case one can only speculate on the reasons why the dependencies' dependencies have been included.